# Entities and Views integration problems

Tags: 7, views, entities

I can't figure this out despite hours (maybe 12hrs) of Googling and experimentation.
I'm trying to integrate my custom entity with views.  I am using Entity API.  I don't normally dump a lot of code in these posts, but I'm not sure where to start with this one.  I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

@googletorp - I tried to follow your tutorial but must be missing something because I just can't get it to work.

Below are the following: 
1)  Entity Declarations
2)  Schema
3)  Screenshot of what's showing up in Views

Entity Declarations

```
    function bse_entity_info()
    {
        $items['bse_type'] = array(
            'label' => t('Basic Storage Entity'),
            'controller class' => 'EntityAPIController',
            'entity class' => 'Entity',
            'base table' => 'bse_type',
            'fieldable' => TRUE,
            'entity keys' => array(
                'id' => 'id',
                'label' => 'label',
                'name' => 'type',
            ),
            'exportable' => FALSE,
            'bundle of' => 'bse',
            'module' => 'bse',
            'access callback' => TRUE,
        );

        $items['bse'] = array(
            'label' => t('Basic Storage Entity'),
            'controller class' => 'EntityAPIController',
            'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
            'entity class' => 'Entity',
            'base table' => 'bse',
            'fieldable' => TRUE,
            'access callback' => TRUE,
            'entity keys' => array(
                'id' => 'bid',
                'bundle' => 'type',
            ),
        'label callback' => 'entity_class_label',
            'bundles' => array(),
            'bundle keys' => array(
                'bundle' => 'type',
            ),
            'view modes' => array(
                'full' => array(
                    'label' => t('Full'),
                    'custom settings' => FALSE,
                ),
            ),
            'module' => 'bse',
        );
        return $items;
    }

    function bse_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info)
    {
     $bundles = entity_load('bse_type');
        foreach ($bundles as $type_name => $type) {
          $entity_info['bse']['bundles'][$type_name] = array(
           'label' => $type->label,
        );
        }
       }
```

Schema

```
function bse_schema()
{
    $schema['bse'] = array(
        'description' => 'BSE Table',
        'fields' => array(
            'bid' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique entry ID.',
            ),
            'type' => array(
                'description' => 'BSE content type.',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 32,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => '',
            ),
            'uid' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
                'description' => "The {users}.uid of the associated user.",
            ),
            'created' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
                'description' => "Timestamp for when this entry was created.",
            ),
            'status' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
                'description' => "Status of content.",
            ),
        ),
        'foreign keys' => array(
            'uid' => array(
                'table' => 'users',
                'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid'),
            ),
            'type' => array(
                'table' => 'bse_type',
                'columns' => array('type' => 'type'),
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('bid'),
    );

    $schema['bse_type'] = array(
        'description' => 'BSE Type Table',
        'fields' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => 'serial',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique ID.',
            ),
            'type' => array(
                'description' => 'BSE type machine name.',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 32,
                'not null' => TRUE,
            ),
            'label' => array(
                'description' => 'The human-readable name of this bse type.',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => '',
            ),
            'module' => array(
                'description' => 'Name of the module that defined this type.',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => '',
            ),
            'disable' => array(
                'type' => 'int',
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => 0,
                'description' => "1 = disabled. 0 = enabled.",
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('id'),
        'unique keys' => array('type' => array('type')),
    );

    return $schema;
}
```

Views

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The entities in Commerce might be useful to you. They use Entity module's wrappers, but have full views support. The GPL programmer's motto: When in doubt, steal code.